# Change chrome extension icon when tab or url changes

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on an extension and I want the icon to change when the active tab or url changes. Here's what i have so far:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Link2QR",
  "description": "chrome_extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {     
    "default_icon":"icon.png",    
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },

  "permissions": [
  "activeTab",
  "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
  "tabs"
   ],

 "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
   }
 ]
}
```

content.js

```
if(onSupportedPageNeedChangeIcon) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ "newIconPath" : "testimage.png" });
}
```

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
   function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
   chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
       path: request.newIconPath,
       tabId: sender.tab.id
   });
});
```

Comment: An incomplete manifest (what is "popup.js" here?) isn't helping

Comment: @Xan Please look here. https://github.com/bwold001/chrome_extension Thanks.

Comment: Information should be _in the question itself_. What if your repository changes later?

Comment: I've updated manifest to what I had when I first asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are handling the message in `popup.js`, which I suppose is running in the browser_action popup page.

`popup.js` thus only runs when the extension button is clicked.

You should instead handle it in `background.js`:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "24": "icon.png",
      "25": "icon.png"
    }
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
   function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
   chrome.browserAction.setIcon({
       path: request.newIconPath,
       tabId: sender.tab.id
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Here's what I have so far.
https://github.com/bwold001/chrome_extension

Comment: You are calling `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` in content.js, that API is only available in background.js, moreover it isn't needed anyway. Remove it and just keep `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`

Comment: Okay thanks, I've updated the repository but it's still not working. Just to be clear, I'm trying to get the icon to change when user either switches to another tab or if the url of current tab changes.